# Improve HL7 FHIR ContactPoint Extension: TEL-address example

Tags: hl7-fhir

I've reviewing the FHIR Extension: TEL-address (https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extension-iso21090-tel-address.html) and at the sample section (https://www.hl7.org/fhir/datatypes-examples.html#ContactPoint) I guess there is a mistake, as valueUrl must be used instead of valueUri.

Hope useful

Martí

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  Please use the 'propose a change' link at the bottom of any page in the FHIR specification to submit a change request.  There's a 1-time free registration (where we verify you're a human), after which you're free to submit any issues you find.

Comment: Hi Lloyd , I've tried both login and create once clicked propose a change link but I am not able to report the improvement, I never get an account on Jira.

Comment: Registering for a new account involves human review.  Your account should now have been activated.